# Anaconda- Jupyter Notebook doesn't launch

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab

When I tried to launch Jupyter Notebook inside of Anaconda, nothing happened. I was using Google Chrome as the default browser and I changed the browser to Firefox.

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

I have created `jupyter_notebook_config.py` and edited notebook.browser section with path to Firefox.

I can open jupyter notebook in Firefox manually on port 8890 but it was using port 8888 in Chrome.

I want to open jupyter notebook inside Anaconda. What might be the solution?

My system OS is Windows.